Surface integral when the surface is given implicitly and $z$ doesn't cancel out
In Thomas' Calculus there's a formula for a surface integral when the surface $S$ is given implicitly by $F(x, y, z)=c$:

if $F$ is a continuously differentiable function, with $S$ lying above its closed and bounded shadow region $R$ in the coordinate plane beneath it, the surface integral of the continuous function $G$ over $S$ is given by the double integral over $R$,
$$\iint_S G(x,y,z)d\sigma = \iint_R G(x,y,z)\frac{|\nabla F|}{|\nabla F \cdot \hat{p}|}dA,$$
where $\hat{p}$ is a unit vector normal to $R$ and $\nabla F \cdot p \neq 0$.

In the examples provided in the textbook the formula works fine because whenever the "shadow region" lies in the $xy$ plane, $z$ cancels out (or the value of the integral can be found using geometry). But what if that wasn't the case?
Consider this slightly modified example from the book: Find the center of mass of a thin hemispherical shell lying above the $xy$-plane of radius $a$ and density $\delta(x,y,z) = z$ (in the original example $\delta$ was constant). With $S$ defined implicitly by $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$, $z \geq 0$, we can calculate $|\nabla f| = 2a$, $|\nabla f \cdot \hat{k}| = 2z$, and so $d\sigma = (a/z)dA$.
Then the mass $M$ is
$$M = \iint_S z d\sigma = \iint_R z\frac{a}{z}dA = a\iint_RdA=\pi a^3.$$
But how to calculate the first moment $M_{xy}$?
$$M_{xy}=\iint_S z\delta d\sigma = \iint_R z^2 \frac{a}{z}dA = a\iint_R z dA = ???$$
How would one proceed from here?

Hint: $z$ is a function of $x,y.$

But what if z cannot be simply expressed as a function of x, y? I'm out of luck?

Construct an example and try to solve it. You cannot expect from me an answer that handles all possible cases.
